# AngularJS : Service for data between controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a page with a main controller and a nested controller for showing details about a product. I want to use a a service in angular to call the server, retrieve a data object and hold that data object. The main controller will call the service to fetch the data and the details controller needs to know it was updated and then access the data. My service looks like this:

```
.service("productService", function ($http, $q) {
    var product = {};
    //interface that is returned
    return ({
        fetchProduct: fetchProduct,
        clearProduct: clearProduct,
        product: product
    });

    function fetchProduct(ID) {
        var request = $http({
            method: "get",
            url: "/online/productdata.ashx?itemID=" + ID,
            params: {
                action: "get"
            }
        });

        return (request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
    };

    function clearProduct() {
        product = {};
    };

    // Transform the error response, unwrapping the application dta from
    // the API response payload.
    function handleError(response) {

        // The API response from the server should be returned in a
        // nomralized format. However, if the request was not handled by the
        // server (or what not handles properly - ex. server error), then we
        // may have to normalize it on our end, as best we can.
        if (
            !angular.isObject(response.data) ||
            !response.data.message
            ) {
            return ($q.reject("An unknown error occurred."));
        }
        // Otherwise, use expected error message.
        return ($q.reject(response.data.message));
    };

    // I attempt to transform the successful response and unwrap the application data
    // from the API response payload.
    function handleSuccess(response) {
        product = response.data;
        console.log("Found Data: " + angular.toJson(response.data))
        return (response.data);
    };
})
```

In my main controller I set a scope object to the service like this:
    $scope.SelectedProduct = productService;

When the user clicks the button to show the product it is called via the $scope handle:
    $scope.SelectedProduct.fetchProduct(ID);

The details controller has the same assignment for the $scope.SelectedProduct. I am new to using services but what I understood is that angular would bind to the service object and changes to the property product would trigger binding to any updates. That is not happening - in fact I do see the data after the fetch operation. In the service I have a console.log on the returned data and it is showing the correct data. However the product property is not getting updated. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong please? Neither controller has access to the data after it is fetched. I understand that I am getting back a promise but the data is never there even after a timeout check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with a factory instead of a service.

[AngularJS: Factory vs Service vs Provider](http://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider/)

Comment: I will mark this answer correct because it is partially what I did to fix it. The real issue is more subtle. When the data call returned data the problem was that instead of assigning the data to a property of the service property this technique effectively changed the pointer to the property so it was lost. I did change it to a factory but I also attach the incoming data to a property of the product object. With this it worked fine. Thanks for the response. This is the first time I have not really got a quick solution and I suspect it is due to my statement of the problem. JS has its quirks.